# Ruby Script Error at Runtime

Tags: ruby, input, stream, terminal

I am running a Ruby script that includes the following:

```
def addCourses 
crns = []

loop do                                   Line 168
    system("clear")
    puts "Your CRNs:".color(:red)
    crns.each do |crn|
        puts "  -> #{crn[:title]} (CRN: #{crn[:crn]})".color(:magenta)
end

    #Prompt for CRN
    alt = (crns.length > 0)  ? " (or just type 'start') " : " "
    input = ask("\nEnter a CRN to add it#{alt}".color(:green) + ":: ") { |q| q.echo = true }        LINE 177     

    #Validate CRN to be 5 Digits 
    if (input =~ /^\d{5}$/) then

        #Display CRN Info
        c = getCourse(input.to_s)
        puts "\nCourse: #{c[:title]} - #{c[:crn]}".color(:red)
        puts "--> Time: #{c[:begin]}-#{c[:end]} on #{c[:days]}".color(:cyan)
        puts "--> Teacher: #{c[:instructor]}".color(:cyan)
        puts "--> Type: #{c[:type]} || Status: #{c[:status]}".color(:cyan)
        puts "--> Availability: #{c[:seats]} / #{c[:capacity]}\n".color(:cyan)

        #Add Class Prompt
        add = ask("Add This Class? (yes/no)".color(:yellow) + ":: ") { |q| q.echo = true }
        crns.push(c) if (add =~ /yes/)

    elsif (input == "start") then
        checkCourses(crns)
    end 
end
end
```

But I'm getting an error:

Your CRNs:

```
Enter a CRN to add it :: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.18/lib/highline.rb:844:in `get_line': The input stream is exhausted. (EOFError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.18/lib/highline.rb:867:in `get_response'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.18/lib/highline.rb:259:in `ask'
from Untitled.rb:177:in `addCourses'
from Untitled.rb:168:in `loop'
from Untitled.rb:168:in `addCourses'
from Untitled.rb:210:in `main'
from Untitled.rb:217
```

I'm not entirely sure what is causing there error as I have similar code elsewhere that has the same basic purpose. What could be the cause of this error? I've included appropriate code line numbers in the top block to the right of the corresponding code.

Comment: "Ruby Script Error at Runtime" is hardly the most descriptive title...

Comment: I don't know enough to give more detail than that

Comment: You can't see that the error involves the `highline` gem and says "The input stream is exhausted"?